# Как запустить сразу все функции из файла?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть некий файл с множеством функций,пример:

```py
import math


def task_integer1():
    """A distance L is given in centimeters.
    Find the amount of full meters of this distance
    (1 m = 100 cm)"""
    try:  # перевірка на помилки
        l = int(input("L (sm) = "))
    except:  # якщо помилка
        print("L must be an INTEGER !!!")
        input("Press enter for exit ...")
    else:  # якщо немає помилки
        res = l // 100
        print("L = ", res, "m")


def task_integer2():
    """A weight M is given in kilograms.
        Find the amount of full tons of this weight
        (1 t = 1000 kg)"""
    try:  # перевірка на помилки
        m = int(input("M (kg) = "))
    except:  # якщо помилка
        print("M must be an INTEGER !!!")
        input("Press enter for exit ...")
    else:  # якщо немає помилки
        res = m // 1000
        print("M = ", res, "t")
```

Когда я запускаю его с консоли то ничего не происходит. Когда же объявляю функцию в конце файла то выполняется только объявленная. А в будущем этих функций будет более сотни... Не обьявлять же каждую из них в конце файла...

P.S. К сожалению по условию задания нельзя все функции объединить в одну

**Как мне запустить все функции сразу?**

Comment: Никак, то что у вас это просто имплементация функций - а то что вы пишите в конце файла  - это и есть вызов функции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isinstance(ob, `types.FunctionType`)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import types, logging    

def execute_task(module_name, deny_func_part=(), deny_startswith_func=(), allow_func=(), startswith_func=()):
    """
    :param module_name: str: имя модуля
    :param deny_func_part: [str]: в именах функций модуля это содержаться не должно
    :param deny_startswith_func: [str]: имена функций модуля начинается так не должны 
    :param allow_func: [str]: имена функций модуля должны называться именно так
    :param startswith_func: [str]: имена функций модуля начинается должны именно так
    """
    module = __import__(module_name)

    for attr in dir(module):
        if (deny_func_part and (any((d in attr) for d in deny_func_part))) or (
                deny_startswith_func and (any(str.startswith(attr, a) for a in deny_startswith_func))) or (
                allow_func and (attr not in allow_func)) or (
                startswith_func and (not any(str.startswith(attr, a) for a in startswith_func))):
            continue

        ob = getattr(module, attr)
        if isinstance(ob, types.FunctionType):
            logging.info(ob.__name__)
            try:
                ob.__call__()  # run
            except Exception as _e:
                logging.exception(ob.__name__)
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # запустить все функции модуля main, кроме содержащих в названии ['test', 'temp', ] и не начинающихся на ['_']
    execute_task('main', deny_func_part=['test', 'temp', ], deny_startswith_func=['_'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Примерно тоже самое что и у @CrasyElf но без `eval`

```
for f in globals().copy():
    if f.startswith('task_'):
        print('Запуск ', f)
        globals()[f]()
```

либо

```
for name, f in globals().copy().items():
    if name.startswith('task_'):
        print('Запуск ', name)
        f()
```

Comment: Да, что-то я сразу не сообразил, что это ж обычный словарь )

Answer (score 2):

Одна функция для запуска задания (вместо кучи однотипных отдельных функций для каждого задания), каждое задание - строка в списке (данные по сути)

```
def execute_task(prompt: str, error_text: str, function, output_format: str):
    try:  # перевірка на помилки
        x = int(input(prompt))
    except:  # якщо помилка
        print(error_text)
        input("Press enter for exit ...")
    else:  # якщо немає помилки
        res = function(x)
        print(output_format.format(res))


tasks = [
    ("L (sm) = ", "L must be an INTEGER !!!", lambda l: l // 100, "L = {} m"),
    ("M (kg) = ", "M must be an INTEGER !!!", lambda m: m // 1000, "M = {} t"),
]

for task in tasks:
    execute_task(*task)
```

Вариант, когда может быть несколько входных переменных:

```
def execute_task(prompts, error_texts, function, calculation_error_text, output_format: str):
    data = []
    
    for prompt, error_text in zip(prompts, error_texts):
        try:
            x = int(input(prompt))
        except:
            print(error_text)
            input("Press enter for exit ...")
            return
        else:
            data.append(x)
    
    try:
        res = function(*data)
    except:
        print(calculation_error_text)
    else:
        print(output_format.format(res))


tasks = [
    (["L (sm) = "], ["L must be an INTEGER !!!"], lambda l: l // 100, "", "L = {} m"),
    (["M (kg) = "], ["M must be an INTEGER !!!"], lambda m: m // 1000, "", "M = {} t"),
    (["U (V) = ", "I (A) = "], ["U must be an INTEGER !!!", "I must be an INTEGER !!!"], lambda u, i: u / i,
        "I must not be 0 !!!", "R = {} Ω"),
]


for task in tasks:
    execute_task(*task)
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так, например, хотя это и не очень хороший стиль:

```
for f in globals().copy():
    if f.startswith('task_'):
        print('Запуск ', f)
        eval(f'{f}()')
```

Должны запустится все функции, которые начинаются на `task_`.

Comment: можно обойтись без `eval`. `globals()[f]()`

Comment: RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

Comment: @CrazyElf Нужно приводить к списку `for f in list(globals()):`, тогда работает

Comment: @SergBocharov Да, я что-то не понял, откуда эта ошибка, то бывает, то нет, для надёжности можно